# UITabBar Arrow Indicator for iPad

Tags: objective-c, uitabbar

Following [this](http://idevrecipes.com/2010/12/17/twitter-app-tab-bar-animation/) tutorial, i ended up with a nice arrow for my UITabBar in iPhone.

Now i wanted to do the same for iPad, but it seems to not work.

I tried

```
- (CGFloat) horizontalLocationFor:(NSUInteger)tabIndex
{   
    CGFloat tabItemWidth;
    CGFloat halfTabItemWidth;
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
        tabItemWidth = 320 / tabBarController.tabBar.items.count;
        halfTabItemWidth = (tabItemWidth / 2.0) - (tabBarArrow.frame.size.width / 2.0);
    }
    else 
    {
        tabItemWidth = 768 / tabBarController.tabBar.items.count;
        halfTabItemWidth = (tabItemWidth / 2) - (tabBarArrow.frame.size.width / 2);
    }

    return (tabIndex * tabItemWidth) + halfTabItemWidth;
}
```

following the example, taking the tabBar dimensions for iPad, but the arrow is still so far from being in the middle of each tab.

Any help?

Comment: For the phone/pod you are deviding by 2.0 and for other devices (the pad) you devide by 2. That should not matter much in this case. In general this is bad style because it comes with a trap sometimes. And those errors can be hard to find. BTW the only real difference between the if and els is the 320 and 768. That plus that you SHOULD support landscape on iPad would suggest some slightly different coding. 
Anyway, the code looks good so far. I would NSLog or debug wether the function returns an appropriate value. If so then I would look somwehere else for the error.

Comment: I'm not supporting the landscape mode, so there won't be any problem. The weird thing is that should work with 768, but it doesn't! That's what i don't get. I'm trying to do some tests, and by dividing the number of the tab bar items by 2, the arrow seems not moving that away.

Comment: Did you check to make sure your else statement is getting called? `NSLog` or breakpoint

Comment: Yes it gets called, the problem is that the arrow is not where it should be (middle of the first tab item) but way on the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in place of the current "horizontalLocationFor" method you have:

```
- (CGFloat) horizontalLocationFor:(NSUInteger)tabIndex
{
    // Get the frame of the selected tab item's view.
    // Add one becuase the first subview is the not a button.
    CGRect tabFrame = [[[[[self tabBarController] tabBar] subviews] objectAtIndex:tabIndex+1] frame];

    // Add tab x to half tab width and substract hald arrow image width to center it.
    return tabFrame.origin.x + (tabFrame.size.width * .5) - (tabBarArrow.frame.size.width * .5);
}
```

The original solution assumed that the tab bar width was the entire screen, but on ipad 4 items only fills a portion of the tab bar width, hence dividing the width by the number of items doesn't get you the correct positions.

Comment: That worked! Great, thank you a lot! Wasn't getting what you explained perfectly.